# find all pages that link to abc.com and all pages under it

Tags: seo

So I have been using the `link:` operator in google search, however, some things aren't clear. For example, does it only show results that point to my site exactly as `www.abc.com` or it also includes `contact.support.com/other` or something like that.

Comment: As per the [Search Operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?p=adv_operators&hl=en) and [help pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en), the `link:` operator shows you pages that link to a _particular page_.

Answer (score 1):

The `link:` operator is known not to show all links to your website. This is by design. Google says it just returns [a sampling of the links to your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en).

If you want to know what links Google knows about your website you need to use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

Comment: so this is pointless? .... `link:*.abc.com/*`

Comment: If you want an accurate count? Yes.

Comment: @Muhammad, that command is also not a valid Google search operator command. That will simply give results for pages that have 'Link' and 'abc' in the content in any context, not necessarily a link to abc

Comment: can it be made valid